Outlook is not accepting html content
I am sending email using java SMTP but outlook is not rendering the text/html content . Here is what is email body what outlook is rendering
<p id="content">Dear User,&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Please treat this as urgent message,&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Thank you</p>
Here is my java code
MimeMessage message = javaEmailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, 3,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("body", dto.getBody());
log.info("body {}",dto.getBody())//<p>Dear User,</p><p></p><p>Please treat this as urgent message,</p><p></p><p>Thank you</p>
String htmlTemplate = getTemplate();
String html = templateEngine.process(htmlTemplate, context);
javaEmailSender.send(message);

Its converting < to &lt; and > to &gt;
i am expecting
  Dear User,

  Please treat this as urgent message,

  Thank you


Outlook doesn't reformat messages.  You're either sending it incorrectly, or you have some kind of filter in the middle that is changing it.

Please show us the code that is sending the email.

@AHaworth please see the edit
